# Process can't open file in mspaint

Tags: c#, process

I am creating instance of Process class and passing in StartInfo.FileName path to MS Paint and as argument path to a file:

```
Process paint = new Process();
paint.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe";
SchemaPath = @"E:\directory\Alisa\0-01\0-01 (1).jpg";
Console.WriteLine(SchemaPath);
paint.StartInfo.Arguments = SchemaPath;
paint.Start();
```

My problem is that - when my file name contains white spaces, mspaint completely ignore the file and throws error. For example when my file has path:

```
E:\directory\Alisa\0-01\0-01abc.jpg
```

Everything works, but when I have file with path:

```
E:\directory\Alisa\0-01\0-01 (1).jpg
```

Paint opens up but throws message:

```
E:\directory\Alisa\0-01\0-01.png was not found.
```

Does anyone know how to handle it?

Comment: @AgentFire sorry, I just didn't understood what you meant until I read kennyzx answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try en-quoting the path like

```
paint.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", SchemaPath);
```

Comment: @AgentFire you deserve that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
fname.Replace(@" ", "");
```

using the above method you can replace your space before processing

```
            Process paint = new Process();
            string fname = @"C:\ Windows\System32\mspaint.exe";
            string k = fname.Replace(@" ", "");
            paint.StartInfo.FileName =k; 
            Console.WriteLine(SchemaPath);
            paint.StartInfo.Arguments = SchemaPath;
            paint.Start();
```

Comment: ee what does it give me when I have a file with whitespace? Paint still can't find the file, except this time he just has wrong path...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim bmpFile As String = "C:\Users\Public\ScreenShot.jpg"
Using BMP As New Bitmap(AxAcroPDF1.Width - 20, AxAcroPDF1.Height) '20 IS ATTEMPT TO CLIP OFF THE SCROLL BAR.
            Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)
                G.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, BMP.Size)
                BMP.Save(bmpFile, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End Using
End Using
Shell("cmd /c mspaint /p " & bmpFile) 'WORKS!
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation what the problem actually is and how it is solved.